# Will intel -03 convert pairs of __m256d instructions into __m512d

Tags: performance, compiler-optimization, intrinsics, icc, avx512

Will a code written for a 256 vectorization register will be compiled to use 512 instructions using the (2019) intel compiler with O3 level of optimization?

e.g. will operations on two __m256d objects be either converted to the same amount of operations over masked __m512d objects or grouped to make the most use out of the register, in the best case the total number of operations dropping by a factor 2?

arch: Knights Landing

Comment: No compilers do that, although it would be an interesting idea for an optionally-enabled optimization pass in GCC or LLVM in loops that are manually unrolled or easy to unroll.  Most valuable for KNL, but also useful for widening SSE code to AVX, and AVX to AVX512 in general.  This is one reason to use auto-vectorization instead of manual if you can still get your compiler to make good asm for current CPUs: it can vectorize differently for future CPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no**: a code written to use AVX/AVX-2 intrinsics is not rewritten by ICC so to use AVX-512 yet (with both ICC 2019 and ICC 2021). There is no instruction fusing. Here is an example (see on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8f93Mfv6r)).

```c
#include <x86intrin.h>

void compute(double* restrict data, int size)
{
    __m256d cst1 = _mm256_set1_pd(23.42);
    __m256d cst2 = _mm256_set1_pd(815.0);
    __m256d v1 = _mm256_load_pd(data);
    __m256d v2 = _mm256_load_pd(data+4);
    __m256d v3 = _mm256_load_pd(data+8);
    __m256d v4 = _mm256_load_pd(data+12);
    v1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v1, cst1, cst2);
    v2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v2, cst1, cst2);
    v3 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v3, cst1, cst2);
    v4 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(v4, cst1, cst2);
    _mm256_store_pd(data, v1);
    _mm256_store_pd(data+4, v2);
    _mm256_store_pd(data+8, v3);
    _mm256_store_pd(data+12, v4);
}
```

Generated code:

```asm
compute:
        vmovupd   ymm0, YMMWORD PTR .L_2il0floatpacket.0[rip]   #5.20
        vmovupd   ymm1, YMMWORD PTR .L_2il0floatpacket.1[rip]   #6.20
        vmovupd   ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]                       #7.33
        vmovupd   ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [32+rdi]                    #8.33
        vmovupd   ymm4, YMMWORD PTR [64+rdi]                    #9.33
        vmovupd   ymm5, YMMWORD PTR [96+rdi]                    #10.33
        vfmadd213pd ymm2, ymm0, ymm1                            #11.10
        vfmadd213pd ymm3, ymm0, ymm1                            #12.10
        vfmadd213pd ymm4, ymm0, ymm1                            #13.10
        vfmadd213pd ymm5, ymm0, ymm1                            #14.10
        vmovupd   YMMWORD PTR [rdi], ymm2                       #15.21
        vmovupd   YMMWORD PTR [32+rdi], ymm3                    #16.21
        vmovupd   YMMWORD PTR [64+rdi], ymm4                    #17.21
        vmovupd   YMMWORD PTR [96+rdi], ymm5                    #18.21
        vzeroupper                                              #19.1
        ret                                                     #19.1
```

The same code is generated for both version of ICC.

Note that using AVX-512 should not always speed up your code by a factor of two. For example, on Skylake SP (server-side processors) there is 2 AVX/AVX-2 SIMD units that can be fused to execute AVX-512 instructions but fusing does not improve throughput (assuming the SIMD units are the bottleneck). However, Skylake SP also supports an *optional* additional 512-bits SIMD units that does not support AVX/AVX-2 (only available on some processors). In this case, AVX-512 can make your code twice faster.

Comment: The question mentioned KNL.  That's heavily optimized for AVX-512, with no higher clock speeds or better throughput for narrower vectors.  Your comments about SKX and Icelake-server are likely relevant for other future readers, though.

Comment: All AVX-512 supporting chips have 2 AVX-512 units: one on the fused p01 and one on p5 (shared with the 256-bit unit on that same port but extended to 512 bits). What varies based on model is whether the p5 port supports FP operations.

Comment: Going from AVX2 to AVX-512 can also be a poor optimisation when you’re running SIMD on most/all cores - clock speed throttling can wipe out most of the benefit. Looks good on single core benchmarks though.

Comment: @PaulR I'd be interested in some refs for your claim whenever you have some time. Thanks!

Comment: @Gaston: well it's mainly from empirical evidence - when porting some AVX2 code to AVX-512 (SKL-X) for an embarallel application I was seeing a reasonable performance improvement when running the code on a single core, but this dropped off dramatically when running the code on all cores. I did a little research and it seems that (for early iterations of SKL-X at least), this was a known limitation, but I don't have any references to hand. I don't know if the situation has improved significantly on more recent CPUs.

Comment: @Gaston: some useful from Daniel Lemire: https://lemire.me/blog/2018/09/07/avx-512-when-and-how-to-use-these-new-instructions/

Comment: @PaulR Were you able to recover the performance increase for many cores by setting some specific flag? e.g. disabling AVX-512. If so, how? We were able to reproduce your results on our Xeon Gold 61XX.

Comment: @Gaston: all our performance-critical code is hand-optimised (i.e. SIMD intrinsics), so for this particular case we just reverted to a prior AVX2 implementation, since the performance gains with AVX-512 overall were minimal (and this also allows us to switch to AMD CPUs in the future, if needed).